# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'gender' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel, framework

Estou tentando iniciar um projeto em laravel e estou recebendo este erro ao selecionar o sexo quando se faz o registro

"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'gender' doesn't have a default value"

```html
return User::create([
            
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'avatar' => $avatar_path,
            'gender' => $data['gender'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
```

Se eu por a opção "Gender" Null no meu phpMyAdmin funciona sem erros, porem nao mostra o sexo e sim "NULL"

Meu html:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Gender</label>

                          <div class="col-md-6">
                          <select name="gender" class="col-md-4 control-label">
                            <option value="male" name="male">Male</option>
                            <option value="female" name="female">Female</option>
                            </select>

                                  @error('gender')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                               </div>
                               </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro geralmente é causado por você não especificar todos os valores enquanto o Strict Mode do Mysql/mariadb está ativo.

Para desativar, abra o my.cnf ou my.ini e adicione a linha `sql_mode=`
Ou execute o comando para desativar temporariamente:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
```

Caso não queira desativar o strict mode, basta especificar todos os valores que estão como não nulo no banco de dados.

Mais detalhes na documentação do [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html)!

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar que ja havia feito isso, na verdade não tinha strict mode e pronto, ainda continuo no erro

Comment: Rode o seguinte comando e poste o resultado:
`SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;`

Se possível poste também a configuração de db do Laravel

Comment: A mostrar registos de 0 - 0 (1 total, A consulta demorou 0,0000 segundos.) continua na mesma.
A migração users é esta https://i.ibb.co/Tt1qVMM/migation.png

Comment: Como assim? não retornou nada?
tente configurar o laravel da seguinte maneira:
'connections' => [
        'mysql' => [
            'strict' => false, 
            'modes' => []
       ]
    ]

Comment: Aqui tenho array para imagem do perfil de cada sexo e o retorno. Elas funcionam correto, porem pra isso o 'Gender' tem que tá NULL na phpmyadmin e o 'Gender' fica como NULL
https://i.ibb.co/LxQ7M8X/return.png

Comment: Consegui, faltava a palavra 'Gender' em Protect fillable

Answer (score 0):

O método create() do Eloquent recebe um array com os valores a serem inseridos pelo modo massassign. Caso uma propriedade não esteja contida no array $fillable da entidade em questão, esse valor é jogado fora.

Considerando a explicação, quase certeza que você não incluiu 'gender' na propriedade $fillable da entidade User.

Então o valor de gender não está sendo enviado para inserir no banco, onde você tenta inserir uma linha sem o gender que é uma coluna requerida da tabela, causando o erro SQL.

Simplesmente vá a sua classe User e adicione todas as propriedades que vão ser salvas no banco no array da propriedade $fillable

Edit:

Recomendo que leia a documentação do laravel antes de usar o framework. Isso é algo bem simples e está bem explicado em sua documentação. Caso tenha problemas com o inglês, pode utilizar do tradutor, pois os texto são bem literais e não perdem muito sua legibilidade ao serem traduzidos por tradutores.